# How to Optionally filter on multiple columns using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So I have created a sheet with a large table of data and 19 columns and have created a userform that is used to generate the sheet with the required data and none of that has been an issue.

I have 5 particular columns (colum 4,5,7,8 and 12) that will be routinely used for filtering the data. As an attempt to incorporate this into the userform I created a ListBox for each column which displays the unique values from that column. An enduser can then multiselect the values they want to filter on from these columns which populate into TextBoxs (one for each ListBox).

Below is the code I have got so far for pulling the values from these text Boxes but when I run it  all filters apply to the corresponding column of whichever textbox was populated first as opposed to their own columns. Not sure is this a limitation or is there anyway around it?

Also just to note it is not a requirement or neccesary for the filters to be used. Some cases will see multiple being used in different combinations and sometimes no filters might be used.

thanks in advance for any help:

```
Sub ApplyFiltersFromTextBoxes()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    ' Set the worksheet and last row
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PDF sheet")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Apply filter based on the entries from TextBox3 (Column 4)
    Dim filterString As String
    Dim filterValues4() As String
    filterString = Trim(TestVersionUpdate.MultiPage1.Pages("Page2").TextBox3.Value)
    If Len(filterString) > 0 Then
        filterValues4 = Split(filterString, ",")
        For i = LBound(filterValues4) To UBound(filterValues4)
            filterValues4(i) = Trim(filterValues4(i))
        Next i
        Set rng = ws.Range("D1:D" & lastRow)
        On Error Resume Next
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filterValues4, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    ' Apply filter based on the entries from TextBox4 (Column 5)
    Dim filterValues5() As String
    filterString = Trim(TestVersionUpdate.MultiPage1.Pages("Page2").TextBox4.Value)
    If Len(filterString) > 0 Then
        filterValues5 = Split(filterString, ",")
        For i = LBound(filterValues5) To UBound(filterValues5)
            filterValues5(i) = Trim(filterValues5(i))
        Next i
        Set rng = ws.Range("E1:E" & lastRow)
        On Error Resume Next
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filterValues5, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    ' Apply filter based on the entries from TextBox5 (Column 7)
    Dim filterValues7() As String
    filterString = Trim(TestVersionUpdate.MultiPage1.Pages("Page2").TextBox5.Value)
    If Len(filterString) > 0 Then
        filterValues7 = Split(filterString, ",")
        For i = LBound(filterValues7) To UBound(filterValues7)
            filterValues7(i) = Trim(filterValues7(i))
        Next i
        Set rng = ws.Range("G1:G" & lastRow)
        On Error Resume Next
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filterValues7, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    ' Apply filter based on the entries from TextBox6 (Column 8)
    Dim filterValues8() As String
    filterString = Trim(TestVersionUpdate.MultiPage1.Pages("Page2").TextBox6.Value)
    If Len(filterString) > 0 Then
        filterValues8 = Split(filterString, ",")
        For i = LBound(filterValues8) To UBound(filterValues8)
            filterValues8(i) = Trim(filterValues8(i))
        Next i
        Set rng = ws.Range("H1:H" & lastRow)
        On Error Resume Next
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filterValues8, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    ' Apply filter based on the entries from TextBox7 (Column 12)
    Dim filterValues12() As String
    filterString = Trim(TestVersionUpdate.MultiPage1.Pages("Page2").TextBox7.Value)
    If Len(filterString) > 0 Then
        filterValues12 = Split(filterString, ",")
        For i = LBound(filterValues12) To UBound(filterValues12)
            filterValues12(i) = Trim(filterValues12(i))
        Next i
        Set rng = ws.Range("L1:L" & lastRow)
        On Error Resume Next
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filterValues12, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be unfiltering the data between filters?

Comment: No @SJR , I want the combination of filters. So for example filter for A ,B and C on columns 4 and also filter for X and Y on column 5 that have A,B or C on column 4. Once I get this working I will have a clear all filters command at the start but never between each column

Comment: I see. This may not remedy your problem but you don't need to separately filter, you can filter the same range and just change the field (column) parameter.

Comment: I realised it was possible but didnt realise how big og any impact that would have! As per the answer below this was on the right track. It seems every time you set the range it changes where previous filters get applied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested but this should be close.  As SJR notes in the comments - you need to filter the whole range and supply each column index.

```vb
Sub ApplyFiltersFromTextBoxes()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, data As Range
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PDF sheet")
    Set data = ws.Range("A1:S" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row)
    
    FilterColumn data, 4, "TextBox3"
    FilterColumn data, 5, "TextBox4"
    FilterColumn data, 7, "TextBox5"
    FilterColumn data, 8, "TextBox6"
    FilterColumn data, 12, "TextBox7"

End Sub

Sub FilterColumn(rng As Range, fieldNum As Long, tbName As String)
    Dim filterValues() As String, filterString As String
    
    filterString = Trim(TestVersionUpdate.MultiPage1.Pages("Page2").Controls(tbName).Value)
    If Len(filterString) > 0 Then
        filterValues = Split(filterString, ",")
        For i = LBound(filterValues) To UBound(filterValues)
            filterValues(i) = Trim(filterValues(i))
        Next i
        On Error Resume Next
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=fieldNum, Criteria1:=filterValues, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That was it! And thank you for the second sub to use. I had a second sub originally but it was giving me more errors then it was worth based on the vairables i was inputting.